# CodeIgniter Update a row of two tables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

My problem here is the `pullout_qty` table column did not update while the description and `date_requested` were updated.

```
function update_save() {
    var cnt = parseInt($('#tblBB_rows_cnt').val());
    var description = $('#form_description').val();
    var status = $('#stat_filter').val();    
    var qty = [];
    var z = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < cnt; x++) {
        if ($('#tblC_visibility' + x).val() == 1) {
            qty[z] = $('#tblC_qty' + x).val();
            z += 1;
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: URL + "index.php/pullout_request/loadEditSave",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            qty: qty,
            description: description,
            status: status
        },
        success: function(data) {
            SYS_pending_setlist();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#dialog1").dialog("close");
            }, 500);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }    
    });
}
```

*There were two separate tables here, `across_pullout` and `across_pullout_items`. When I update it only the  `across_pullout` was updated. The `pullout_qty` in `across_pullout_items` becomes 0 (output)*

```
$pullout_qty=$_POST['qty']; 
$status=$_POST['status'];
$date_requested=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$description=$this->db->escape_str($_POST['description']);
$sql .= "UPDATE `across_pullout` SET date_requested='$date_requested', `description`='$description' where status='0' and remark='1';";
$sql.= "UPDATE across_pullout_items set pullout_qty='$pullout_qty' where remark='1';";
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried my ans.. ? is It work for you ..?

Comment: Mannu saraswat  thanks for your suggestion. I solved it now. The problem was in js.

Comment: Great ... But you have to use CI prebuild function to maintain the CI standard in place of using core methods if You are using any framework... Happy Coding...

Answer (score 2):

Make me correct if I am not wrong.
In Codeigniter,
 You can't update multiple tables with one SQL statement. Codeigniter does allow you to use transactions though. like below

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Here are the complete documents for this [Transactions](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html) please check it out...
which will also help you to run both queries together, Advantage of using transaction  it will only insert data when both query return success...